# RuntimeError: expected scalar type Float but found Double error torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, cross-entropy

I am trying to train a pytorch model. The loss function is:

```
cn_loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=train_label_weight, reduction='mean')
```

Code fragment from the training function:

```
for sents, targets in batch_iter(df_train, batch_size=train_batch_size, shuffle=True, bert=bert_size):
        train_iter += 1
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        batch_size = len(sents)
        pre_softmax = model(sents)
        float_targets=torch.tensor(targets, dtype=torch.float, device=device)

        loss = cn_loss(pre_softmax, float_targets)
        
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Data types of both `pre_softmax` and `float_targets` is `torch.float32`. (In the original code data type of the `targets` has been converted to `torch.int64` using `torch.tensor(targets, dtype=torch.long, device=device)`. However as I get the

> RuntimeError: expected scalar type Float but found Double

error I converted the data type of `targets` to `torch.float32`)

Even though both parameters in `cn_loss()` function are `torch.float32`,  I get the below error when I run the code:

> loss = cn_loss(pre_softmax, float_targets)
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
> return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 1152, in forward
> label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing)
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2846, in cross_entropy
> return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
> RuntimeError: expected scalar type Float but found Double

I checked the data types multiple times and changed the data type of `float_targets` using `torch.FloatTensor(targets)` also. But I get the same error.

Comment: What about `train_label_weight`? Are they `torch.float32` too?

Comment: It was `torch.float64`. When I converted it to `torch.float32` and changed `targets` to `torch.long` back again, the code worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @aretor in comments, the data type of `train_label_weight` was `torch.float64`. When converted it to `torch.float32` and changed targets to `torch.long` back again, the code worked perfectly

Comment: I faced the same problem and it resolved my problem, thx!